# Creating a Function in dplyr that Operates on Columns through Variable/String Manipulation

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working with a dataset that contains many columns that are similarly named (ex `thing_1` , `thing_2`, `blargh_1`, `blargh_2`, `fizz_1`, `fizz_2`), and I've been trying to write a function that takes in a string (such as `fizz`) and performs some operation on all superstrings of the column (such as `fizz_1 + fizz_2`).

So far, I have structured my code into something that looks something like:

```
newData <- data %>%
    mutate(fizz = f("fizz"))

f <- function(name) {
name_1 + name_2
}
```

where `f` as written obviously doesn't work. I've toyed around with `assign`, but not been terribly successful. I'm also open to other ways to tackle the problem (maybe a function that takes in a dataset and the string). Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we are creating a function then make use of the `select_helpers` which can take `starts_with` or `ends_with` or `match` as arguments

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
f1 <- function(data, name){
          data %>%
              mutate(!! name := select(., starts_with(name)) %>% reduce(`+`))
    }

f1(df1, "fizz")
f1(df1, "blargh")
f1(df1, "thing")
#   thing_1 thing_2 thing_3 fizz_1 fizz_2 blargh_1 blargh_2 thing
#1       1       6      11      2      3        4        5    18
#2       2       7      12      3      4        5        6    21
#3       3       8      13      4      5        6        7    24
#4       4       9      14      5      6        7        8    27
#5       5      10      15      6      7        8        9    30
```

Or specify `select(., matches(str_c("^", name, "_\\d+$")))`

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(thing_1 = 1:5, thing_2 = 6:10, thing_3 = 11:15, 
    fizz_1 = 2:6, fizz_2 = 3:7, blargh_1 = 4:8, blargh_2 = 5:9)
```

Comment: Interesting! Is is possible to explain `!! name := ` ? thanks

Comment: Thanks! That's a very neat and compact solution

Comment: @ZhiqiangWang  That notation is specific to tidyverse for `assignment` (`:=`) with `lhs` being a object.  here, we evaluate (`!!`) to get the value in `name` instead of creating name as the column name

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is handy and I will definitely try it with my work!